# Const pointer in a class object-oriented bug

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, oop, constants

I have a simple example below that does not compile. i get the following warrning about const

**Error message:** 
*error C2662: 'Cfoo::GetNum' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Cfoo' to 'Cfoo &' Conversion loses qualifiers*

```
class Cfoo 
{
    public:
        bool RunMe( const Cfoo * bar ) {
            int i = bar->GetNum() ; 
        }

        int GetNum() {
            return 7; 
        }
};   

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Cfoo a;

    Cfoo b;
    b.RunMe( &a); 

    return 0;
}
```

At first I though that had something to do with the GetNum not returning a const value. changing that did not seem to help.

What did I do wrong?, suggestion, hints, examples, links?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GetNum` must promise it does not change the value of the object by making it a const member function

```
class Cfoo 
{
    public:
        bool RunMe( const Cfoo * bar ) {
            int i = bar->GetNum() ; 
        }

        int GetNum() const { // !!!
            return 7; 
        }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

litb's solution is right thereon.

However, I would like to do my bit to elaborate on what the compiler message actually means and how to decipher it.

So, here is a longer explanation of the error message and how to understand it in this context. I hope all the gurus here would correct my understanding.

> "error C2662: 'Cfoo::GetNum' : cannot
>   convert 'this' pointer from 'const
>   Cfoo' to 'Cfoo &' Conversion loses
>   qualifiers"

1. The type of `'bar'` is `'Cfoo const *'.`

A member function such as `'GetNum'` in OP is *considered* to be declared as

> int Cfoo::GetNum(Cfoo &dummyimpliedobjectparameter); // the implied object argument as per `13.3.1/3 and /4`

In accordance with `13.3.1.1.1/2`

The function call `bar->GetNum()` is treated as `(*bar).GetNum(*bar)` where `(*bar)` is the `implied object argument`

Now, this means that, an object of type `'Cfoo const'` has to be bound to a reference of type `'Cfoo &'`, to match the function call argument to the function parameter. As per `8.5.3/5'`, this is not allowed as a `reference to non const` cannot bind to a `const`.

So as litb suggested, the way to bail out is to make `Cfoo::GetNum` as a `const` member function. As per `13.3.1/3`, with this change, the member function `Cfoo::GetNum` now is considered as

`int Cfoo::GetNum(Cfoo const &dummyimpliedobjectparameter);  // note the const`

Now, the member function 'call' and 'parameter' match exactly and the code is well-formed.

> @Steven: Does the compile error make more sense
>   now?